# Analogue for English construction "the more... the more..."

Tags: traduction, adjectifs, comparatifs, constructions

English has a grammatical construction for comparative adjectives, that looks like, for example:

> The more books I read, the more I know.

This construction uses two comparative adjectives to show dependency between two things. Is there an analogue for that in French? Or any another good way to say this?

I started learning French recently, and tried to explain this to my teacher, but I don't think she understood me (she doesn't speak English). Also I tried to find this on Google and here, but had no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est un cas où le mot à mot fonctionne :

> *Plus* je lis de livres, *plus* je sais (ou *plus* je connais).

Une traduction plus soutenue :

> *Plus* je lis de livres, *plus* je sais de choses.

Une traduction avec transposition :

> *Plus* je lis de livres, *plus* mes connaissances augmentent.